# jquery html get visible item data-foo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have some problem.

I write html code where have about 100 div.

```
<?php
    for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
    {                    
        $post_block = '
        <div id="1_%s" class="simple_wall_post" data-foo="bar_%s">

        </div>';

        $s = sprintf($post_block,$i,$i);
    }
?>
```

windowsHeight = 10000 px
1 div element height = 100 px

For example facebook autoplay video, if video visible then played, if no stopped.
I can't get current div-foo when visible on window.
how can I implement it? thank you.

Comment: First thing: IDs must be unique.

Comment: 100 `div`s on a page? What a page!

Comment: Use echo statement to show on page. alone calling sprintf won't work

Comment: yes id I change , id is unique,

Comment: but what is a jquery code I would be use ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to determine the scrolling of the page, as suggested here: [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Like this:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```